# Securing tables vs databases on a mutitool web site with confidential information

Tags: mysql, database, security

I am working on a site that multiple projects will be using to enter confidential subject information for various research projects.  Project data access will be limited to specific users and tools.  But certain core data will be referenced in and joined to the project tables (username, project meta-data, etc).  The current plan is that each project will have mysql users with any combination of Select, Update, or Insert rights as needed.  Plus an overall project Adminstrator user that can alter the shape of the project's tables that will only be used in phpadmin.  We are using a Database object with some backtrace logic to determine what object passed it connection credentials and will only allow that connection to be used by the originating object (not impossible to get around by a dedicated programmer, but would throw up red flags in code review).  And we are following standard procedure of moving the config out of the web root and keeping all credentials in config files instead of code.  Of course there is an overall administrator but that has so many access rules and it's password is ludicrously long (we have a static yubikey + 10 char password).

What I want to know is whether to separate project data out to their own databases or should I put them in tables that have access limited to certain accounts?  Setting user permissions on the Database or Table level seem to be about equitable in difficulty.  There will be joins and other such operations between the core tables (meta-data usually) and the protected data.  But joining across databases on the same server works fine, but I am uncertain about how the performance of intra-database joins compare to inter-database joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter if you put them in the same database or in different ones. You can implement a good (or a bad) security concept with both alternatives.

if you are using one database and you put data for different users in one table you will have to implement a lot of the access control in you application.

if you have separated the data completely in different tables (or even databases) you can easily use the access control of mysql. In this case I would go with separated databases, because it is more convenient when setting up a backup system or if you want to scale your application over more than one machine. But since you want to join across different databases you gonna lose some of these advantages so it doesn't really matter.